# What will use to delete the empty value of an array with a minimum of time?

Tags: php, arrays, performance

I want to delete the value from the array. What you offer will use as an optimization option with a minimum of time loss. Here by the way, the value with spaces can not be deleted. For example I used array_filter() to this task:

```
$array = array(null, " ", false, "apple", "", "- ", "   .");

echo "<pre>";
   print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";

/* Output */

Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] =>  
    [2] => 
    [3] => apple
    [4] => 
    [5] => - 
    [6] =>    .
)


$array = array_filter($array);

echo "<pre>";
   print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";

/* Output */

Array
(
    [1] =>  
    [3] => apple
    [5] => - 
    [6] =>    .
)
```

What do you suggest using to remove an empty value from an array: a loop or function array_filter() or something else?

Comment: `array_filter()` without a callback argument is exactly what I'd use. It does precisely what you want and there's likely not a faster method.

Comment: OP wants to remove items with some spaces, but `array_filter($arr)` does not

Comment: I want to remove all tabs and spaces from the array value except for null values

Comment: `array_walk($array, function (&$value, $key) use ($array) { ... })` should do the trick. you could do an `unset($array[$key])` in cases you want

Comment: Please provide your example in the form of an answer to the question with an example of a working code that everyone could appreciate your idea with your code. We need to look at the speed of the program code @ceadreak

Answer (score 0):

Examples with both methods `array_filter` and `array_walk`

**array_walk example**

```
$array = [null, " ", false, "apple", "", "- ", "   ."];

$start = microtime(true);
array_walk($array, function (&$value, $key) use (&$array) {
    if (empty(trim($value)) && !is_null($value))
    {
        unset($array[$key]);
    }
});
$end = microtime(true);

var_dump([$array, $end-$start]);
```

will output

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => null
      3 => string 'apple' (length=5)
      5 => string '- ' (length=2)
      6 => string '   .' (length=4)
  1 => float 2.0980834960938E-5
```

**array_filter example**

```
$array = [null, " ", false, "apple", "", "- ", "   ."];

var_dump($array);

$start = microtime(true);
$array = array_filter($array, function ($entry) {
    return (!empty(trim($entry)) || is_null($entry));
});
$end = microtime(true);

var_dump([$array, $end-$start]);
```

will output

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => null
      3 => string 'apple' (length=5)
      5 => string '- ' (length=2)
      6 => string '   .' (length=4)
  1 => float 1.6927719116211E-5
```

Conclusion: array_filter is better !

Answer (score 0):

array_keys should be faster:

```
$array = array(...);

$keys = array_keys($array,"");

foreach ($keys as $k){
    unset($array[$k]);
}
```